# adding multimedia files in a database

Tags: database, file, addition, multimedia

how to add multimedia files(such as images) in a database(SQL SERVER or ORACLE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a BLOB column type. Why can't you just store references to the paths of the media though, which is the most common?

Comment: could u explain a little about BLOB column type

Comment: Though this article may be dated/deprecated or whatever, it would better than I can: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3719221/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server.htm